# Transfering data from Express.js backend to a React frontend

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to transfer data to my react frontend with axios and I dont understand why its not working[the getData function is where I am trying to recieve the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Hl3.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how we fetch data using axios, so first of all you should define the base url headers and other optional configuration in separate file (best practice).

client.js :

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000", //Define your own base url it's better to use env variables
  timeout: 60000, //Timout 1 min
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
});
```

Then you can use axios. I recommend using async/await, the syntax will be clearer and easy to maintain :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "./client";

function App(){
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(async ()=>{
        const response = await axios.get("/getbitcoin");
        setData(response?.data)
    }, []);
    return(
        <>
            <ul>
                {data.map((row)=><li>{JSON.stringify(row)}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```